# How to get followers activity in my activity wall in buddypress

Tags: wordpress, buddypress

Generally buddypress have default activity page member/username/activity

In this page or any custom page i need to get my following user's activities feed

Comment: @DavidW do you think this is not about programming. I will post my solution.

Comment: @DavidW refer below solution,

Comment: Fair enough - I misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
   <?php if ( bp_has_activities( bp_ajax_querystring( 'activity' ) .'&object=friends' ) ) :  ?>

   <?php //if ( bp_has_activities( bp_ajax_querystring( 'activity' ) ) ) : ?>
       <?php while ( bp_activities() ) : bp_the_activity(); ?>

           <?php locate_template( array( 'buddypress/activity/entry.php' ), true, false ); ?>

       <?php endwhile; ?>
   <?php endif; ?>
```

object optional

The object type to filter on (can be any active component ID as well as custom component ID’s)

Example arguments: groups, friends, profile, status, blogs
Default value: false (no filter)